# Vertical Scrollbar Position Absolute

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Is there a way to have a cross browser vertical scrollbar with an absolute position?

My problem is that the scrollbar changes the width of my website when appears by giving some issues in my layout.

I do not want to remove it, I just want to make its width not disturbing my layout..

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To stop your layout from moving when the scrollbar appears, you can use the css below to always make your scrollbar visible.

```
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. It surely stops layout moving, but you break any css padding / margin symmetry. What if you want in the future to change all the margins of your app or the width of your scrollbar ?

Answer (score 56):

Only in Safari and Chrome (ie. Webkit), you can also use:

```
html{
    overflow-y: overlay;
}
```

It will add a scroll bar only when necessery, and put it above your content, which means it will not disturb your layout.
Use with caution though, it's proprietary and undocumented.

Comment: awesome! I didn't know this existed

Comment: overlay is now depracated
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: Great. This is the first time I know that the "overlay" property exists. 
This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 18):

Since nobody has mentioned it, if you want to use `overlay` when it's available *(e.g., Chrome & Safari)* and fallback to `scroll` when it's not, you can use the following.

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

always display it to not disturb your layout. it's what Google do ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use below style.

```
scrollbar-gutter: stable;
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999257/vertical-scrollbar-position-absolute/62943795#comment127609284_34503125) said `overflow: overlay;` is depracated.

> My problem is that the scrollbar changes the width of my website when
> appears by giving some issues in my layout.

So, I think we can [scrollbar-gutter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-gutter). (Maybe we have to change margins or padding)

```
scrollbar-gutter: stable;
/* or /
scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;
```

Answer (score 0):

"The keyword value `overlay` is a legacy value alias for `auto`." states [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

However, when using `overflow` in conjunction with `scrollbar-gutter`, it creates the effect that the scrollbar floats, **if the content has the width of the page**:

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-gutter: stable both-edges;
}

.content {
  width: 100vw; /* metrics like 100% should also work */
}
```