# How to prevent page content from shift when scroll appears?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am currently working on project about car travelling http://wayfi.ru and

I have encountered a problem recently - page content shifts to the left after vertical scroll appears. How to prevent this?

As I know, one could always display disabled scroll and make it enable if there is necessary.

Do you know better technique to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid I do not know of any other way to do this apart from always showing the scrollbar, active or not.

The simplest way I think is:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

This way, even on pages without scrolling there is space reserved for the scrollbar and the content won't jump around between pages.

Comment: The OP specifically asks for a way that doesn't involve showing the scrollbar the whole time.

Comment: @tw16: As far as I know, there is no better fix.

Comment: You should set it on `html` instead of `body` to avoid edge case problems such as [this](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pintyo/archive/2010/11/06/double-scrollbars-with-quot-overflow-y-scroll-quot-on-ie7-when-using-cssstickyfooter.aspx) in IE7.

Comment: @thirtydot: I agree. I don't know one either. But I was pointing out that the OP already knew about this solution and was asking if there was a better/different way to solve the problem.

Comment: @tw16, my bad for not understanding the question properly.

Comment: I still think your answer is the correct technique. In fact I gave a very similar [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999257/vertical-scrollbar-position-absolute/7001779#7001779) just yesterday! But given the wording of the question, I think you should just explain that you do not know of any other way of to achieve it etc. (Though as @thirtydot said I would use html not body)

Comment: One of my friend offered me another way to do it - one could create custom javascript scroller and hide default at all. What do you think about that?